# How to filter the same id as the URL Params?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a mock database that looks like this

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "jobTitle": "Budget/Accounting Analyst III",
    "companyName": "Topiclounge",
    "city": "Duluth",
    "state": "Minnesota",
    "country": "United States",
    "jobDescription": "egestas metus aenean fermentum donec ut mauris eget massa tempor convallis nulla neque libero convallis eget eleifend luctus ultricies eu nibh quisque id justo sit amet sapien dignissim vestibulum vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae nulla dapibus dolor vel est donec odio justo sollicitudin ut suscipit a feugiat et eros",
    "datePosted": "1/23/2020"
  }, 
...
]
```

and so on.

I want to retrieve the object with the id that matches the id from the urlParams which I am getting from useParams();
I am using this axios.get request

```
const getJobById = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await Axios.get(`https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5ff798661d107958ae4ca82b`)
      console.log(response.data, id)
      const job = response.data.filter(item => item.id === id)[0]
      console.log(job)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

To retrieve data from the mock api and to filter out the object that matches this id, however I am getting an undefined from console.log(job)
How can i filter this data in the correct way?

Comment: Where are you declaring your `id` variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `response.data.find(item => item.id === id)` instead but that is likely not going to fix your problem.

To be able to further assist you, could you please share what this line prints into the console:

> console.log(response.data, id)

Based on the OP's response in the comments below, the problem is that `===` is also checking for the same type. Since the variable id is a String and the value of the id key in the object of the api output is a Number `item.id === id` will always return false. You could either just use `==` in this case or you should convert the String id to a Number: `id = Number(id)`.

Or just what the OP actually did to solve it:

```
item.id === parseInt(id)
```

Comment: It looks like 1000 objects in the array
[ {...}, {...}, {...} ]
and id is one of the properties in the object

Comment: Can you share a bit more of your code? Where is the variable id declared that is being used in the filter function and which value does it have?

Comment: const { id } = useParams(); , and id is the value from the "URL" for example /job-detail/1
and id would be 1

Comment: It could be that id is a String as it comes from the URL. Please check that with the following code: `console.log(typeof id)` and let me know what the output is.

Comment: The problem is that `===` is also checking for the same type. Since the variable id is a String and the value of the id key in the object of the api output is a Number `item.id === id` will always return false. You could either just use `==` in this case or you should convert the String id to a Number: `id = Number(id)`

Comment: Thanks man, i just did ```item.id === parseInt(id)```

Comment: Yes, that's also possible. I'm glad I could help you! :)

Comment: I have edited your answer to include the actual solution from your comments above.